# Endpoint Validation(@Valid, @Pattern, etc) with Optional

Tags: java, spring, annotations, spring-annotations

We have a need to have certain objects be wrapped in an optional because we need to know three states:

- Missing (not present)
- Null (present but null)
- Data (present with data)

Currently we are wrapping these fields with Optional because spring rest endpoint will give us these states as null, Optional.empty() and Optional.of(value).

**However, it does not appear that the validations are working.  Do I need to do something different than just add @Valid, @Pattern, @NotNull, etc??**

Note: there is a more detail breakdown of the need in this question ([Java Spring (Jackson) Annotation for Not Present, Present but Null, and Present with Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67199661/java-spring-jackson-annotation-for-not-present-present-but-null-and-present))

Comment: Check this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47020795/validating-optional-field)

Answer (score 0):

Add javax.validation dependency

Below are the 3 steps to add validation.

1. Add @NonNull on the data member in the POJO class

```
    class Employee
    {
        @NonNull
        String name;
    }
```

2. Create following method

```
    private void validate(Employee emp){
        ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
        Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
        Set<ConstraintViolation<Employee>> violations = validator.validate(emp)
        for(ConstraintViolation<Employee> violation: violations) {
            //Your action. May be throw exception
        }
    }
```

3. Add @Valid where the object is used and invoke the validate method

```
    void method(@Valid Employee emp){
        validate(emp);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So the best solution that I found was to use Jakarta validations instead of Javax because the Jakarta will look into the optional field and apply the validation annotations.